# How to send two emails with devise authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise-confirmable

i'm new on ruby on rails, i want to send two emails when a user create a account in my project, so, when the user sends a request inserting email and password, i want to send email confirmable for your email and send a message informing the request of a user for my email. How do i resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a callback.

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :send_admin_mail

    ...

    def send_admin_mail
        AdminMailer.new_user(self)
    end
end
```

Mailer

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def new_user(user)
        @user = user
        mail(subject: 'A new user has signed up!!111')
    end
end
```

You'll have to adjust the mailer settings (ie: `default to:` should be the people you want notified of new user sign ups.

More info available at

[1]: [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

[2]: [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)